# I need a batch file that will create a directory of text files based on a text file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I would like a batch file that reads every line of a text file and creates a blank text file whose name corresponds to each line in the text file, regardless of spaces, and then puts them into C:\temp. I should be able to drag the text file onto the batch file to make it produce everything.

Example:
The original text file sample.txt says:

> This is a file (haha)
>
> This is another file
>
> I need this file.

This should create these three files in the directory C:\temp:

> This is a file (haha).txt
>
> This is another file.txt
>
> I need this file..txt

I think it should be something like this:

```
for /f %%i in (c:\temp\sample.txt) do echo %%i > "c:\temp\%%i.txt"
```

But this only makes a file for the first word in the text file, not each line.
Please help.

Comment: The line I wrote in in the question

Comment: Wrap the filename with quotes for a start. "c:\temp\%%i.txt"

Comment: Try adding the "tokens=*" option

Comment: What do you want the contents of the text files to be? should they contain their names, so the original lines from `c:\temp\sample.txt`? this is what your code does, supposing you added the `"tokens=*"` option...

Comment: @aschipfl I just want empty text files. I want the filenames of each empty  to be taken from each line of sample.txt. As, I realize it would be better if I could just drag and drop any text file onto the batch file, not just c:\temp\sample.txt.

Comment: To create an empty file, use `> "c:\temp\%ii.txt" break` or `> "c:\temp\%ii.txt" rem/` in your code instead of `echo %%i > c:\temp\%ii.txt`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the "tokens=*" option so that it accepts characters like spaces. Your code would look like this:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (c:\temp\sample.txt) do copy /y nul "c:\temp\%%i.txt"
```